# Retrieve text (not value) from select option tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using asp.net c# mvc4

I can currently retrieve the value of selected option in my controller from my view, but I also need to retrieve the text. My View and Controller looks like this:

View:

```
<form method="post" action="myAction">
     <select name="sel">
          <option value="1" text="One">One</option>
          <option value="2" text="Two">Two</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult myAction(int sel) 
{
     int selValue = sel;
}
```

This piece of code works fie for me. However, in my controller, I want to add `string selText=something` so that I have the text too, and the code would look like:

```
public ActionResult myAction(int sel, string something) 
{
     int selValue = sel;
     string selText = something
}
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: I'm not sure what the `something` part should be. The `int sel` part selects the value of the selected option which works fine for me. How do I select the text from the selected option and not the value?

Comment: So you want to get the inner text of the option, you won't be able to do that without introducing some javascript (or some other component in the browser).  An HTML form submission _only_ includes the value of the `input` control(s).

Comment: Yeah, either the inner text or the `text="One"` part (I hope that's not the inner text).

Comment: How would I integrate js with c# so that I have the text in my controller?

Comment: You could try to put both the value and the text into the value attribute using a separator. Like this: `value="1|One"` and separate it in the controller again.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly Has a good suggestion, but your method would still only take a single `string` parameter and the OP would have to split that one parameter into the appropriate values.  That would be **much** simpler that trying to write a lot of javascript.

Comment: Works like a charm! You guys are awesome! Thanks so much! @JennyO'Reilly Please put your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the answer for this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put both (the value and the text) into the value attribute using a separator.

```
<form method="post" action="myAction">
      <select name="sel">
          <option value="1|One">One</option>
          <option value="2|Two">Two</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

And separate it in the controller again.

```
public ActionResult myAction(string sel) 
{
    string[] selSplit = sel.Split('|');
    int selValue = int.Parse(selSplit[0]);
    string selText = selSplit[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally you cannot get the text as the form posts only the value of the select. But you can populate the select list dynamically from server(in the model or in ViewBag) and when you receive a post with the value - get the text corresponding to the value.

This is a so common pattern that it won't need any explanation. You never post the text back indeed as you don't need it.

Anyway here is the code:

```
public ActionResult myAction(int sel) 
{ 
   int selValue = sel; 
   string text= yourRepository.GetById(sel)?.YourText; 
 }
```

Comment: I already have my answer from the comments above, but your suggestion sounds interesting too. As a matter of fact, I AM generating my list dynamically from server (in model). The code above was just a sample. Would you be able to elaborate more on how to get the text corresponding to the value using this method?

Comment: `public ActionResult myAction(int sel) 
{
     int selValue = sel;
     string text= yourRepository.GetById(sel)?.YourText; 
  }`

You have another call to DB but you will not split values based on separators which is error prone.

Comment: Yes, this is a nice solution. Use something like a `Dictionary<int, string>` in the Controller and pass it to the View to dynamically build your select list. This way you can use it in the View and back in the Action method of the Controller by calling `myDictionary[sel]` (sel is an int in this case).